# XBRL Table link blocked cells

Tags: xml, xsd, visualization, instance, xbrl

What should I fix to make all cells open to edit? Now I can't fill the table, because of blocked cells.

I think that some cells of the table are blocked and this problem is related to hypercubes: positive hypercube minus negative hypercube = cells that should be filled in and must be open to edit.
Maybe I'm thinking in the wrong way. Could anyone explain me the logic how to fix blocked grey cells, please?

[screenshot of the table with blocked cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk347.png)

Comment: The XML is not binding to the table.  Does the Xml contain a namespace?

Comment: I've definition, presentation and formula linkbases. In the definition there are links to the hypercubes

Comment: I looks like you created a grey rectangle that is in front of the cells instead of inside the cells which is blocking the text in the cells.